# Creating dynamic type collections and arrays

Tags: c#, .net, list, sorting, interface

Lets say I have an interface passed to my method:

```
public void AlphaToChar(iList _blah)
{

}
```

Out of IList I want to extract it's members Type and use its type to create other Arrays or Lists in the method. See example below.

The "List = new List();" part doesn't work because, as I assume it's a type variable, not the actual type.
Any way around this ? How can I accomplish this and create a new collection of an extracted Type?

```
Type[] listTypes =  list.GetType().GetGenericArguments();
Type listType = null;
if (listTypes.Length>0)
{
   listType = listTypes[0];
}
List<listType> = new List<listType>();
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the `List<>` construction using the following:

```
// Find the generic argument type of your old list (theList)
Type genericType = theList.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];

// Create a new List with the same generic type as the old one
Type newListType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(genericType);

// Create a new instance of the list with the generic type
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(newListType);
```

But it's only going to work if you are using generic lists. The example you gave was using a regular `IList`. You would have to change your method signature to use a generic `IList<>`:

```
public void AlphaToChar(IList<Something> _blah) { }
```

Or make it even more generic:

```
public void AlphaToChar<T>(IList<T> _blah) /* where T : ISomething, new() */ {}
```

Without doing so, you should know what your `IList` is going to contain and you wouldn't have to use reflection to figure out what its elements types are.

Comment: That's the problem. I dont know what is the type of my IList and that's why I need to find it. Once I have the instance variable, how can I work with it as a List type so I can for example Sort() it?

Thanks for all the help

Comment: @Sev, bear in mind that other classes than `List<T>` can implement `IList` and there is no requirement for a collection implementing `IList` to be specialized to a particular type.  The implementer has the option of only allowing a particular type (throwing exceptions if this is violated), but it is also free to accept any type or even use more complex rules to decide what's allowed.

Answer (score 2):

This dynamically constructs a generic `List<T>` for the specified element type:

```
IList list = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(elementType));
```

Note that the result variable is not statically typed to the specialized list, since you don't know the type at compile time.  As such, it's not possible for it to be statically typed.  You're taking advantage of the fact that `List<T>` also implements `IList` here.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Collections.IList list = 
Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<>)
.MakeGenericType(listTypes[0])) as System.Collections.IList;
```